# Python multiprocessing.Process OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
def formatGravities(gravities):
    # create a list to keep all processes
    processes = []

    # create a list to keep connections
    parent_connections = []

    formatted_gravities = []

    # create a process per instance
    for gravity in gravities:
        # create a pipe for communication
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        parent_connections.append(parent_conn)

        # create the process, pass arguments
        process = Process(target=formatGravity,
                          args=(gravity, child_conn))
        processes.append(process)

    # start all processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # make sure that all processes have finished
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    for parent_connection in parent_connections:
        formatted_gravities.append(parent_connection.recv()[0])

    return formatted_gravities
```

`len(gravities)` is on the magnitude of millions. I can understand that I'd not be able to open millions of processes at the same time, and thats probably why I get the error, but how can i change my code so that it waits to spawn processes if max number of processes are already spawned.

I do have the requirement that I can’t use multiprocessing.Queue or multiprocessing.Pool.

Comment: Why can't you use `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I am going to put this code on AWS lambda and lambda does not support it. see this link for more information https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: aws lambda also has requirement of only 1024 file descriptors

Comment: Couldn't you use something like SQS with lambda to offload the processing? What are you doing with the result?

Comment: @IainShelvington, my requirement is to a) fetch all gravity objects from the database and iterate over them format each one. (i can format each one concurrently)  b) pass those formatted gravity objects to another function that iterates over them and mutates each one (i can mutate each one concurrently). the thing thats a little tricky is that the mutate method that takes in the list of gravities also takes in some other data that acts as constants fetched from the database. the data constants are a lot of data and can only be computed once per execution of the entire main function.

Comment: @IainShelvington and at the end i need to operate on the full data set. is this something i can accomplish with SQS?

Comment: @IainShelvington there is no way to join child processes if i use sqs

Comment: Even i am facing the same problem. Did you find the solution for this ?
prossess.terminate() helps ?

Comment: @ChiragKamat yes we did solve it. AWS lambda has a requirement of only 1024 file descriptors. This means that we created 1024 threads (we actually used less) at a time and created batches of concureency

Comment: @yasgur99 i know it's been almost 2 years, but can you please put your solution as an answer as i am looking at doing the same thing. Thanks